# How to name a composite class like this?

Tags: java, class, composite, sql2o

Our team are using Spring Boot 2 with [sql2o](https://www.sql2o.org/) as db library. In the paste in our services, for trivial methods, we simply call the repository and returns the model. For example, if I have a Supplier table, I had in the service

```
@Override
public List<Supplier> findAll() {
    return supplierRepository.findAll();
}
```

Now, since in our controllers we need 99% in the cases other objects correlated to the model, I would create a composite class that holds the model and other models. For example:

```
@Override
public List<UnknownName> findAll() {
    List<Supplier> suppliers = supplierRepository.findAll();

    List<UnknownName> res = new ArrayList<>();

    UnknownName unknownName;
    LegalOffice legalOffice;

    if (suppliers != null) {
        for (Supplier supplier in suppliers) {
            unknownName = new UnknownName();
            unknownName.setSupplier(supplier);
            legalOffice = legalOfficeService.findByIdlegaloffice(supplier.getLegalofficeid);
            unknownName.setLegalOffice(legalOffice);
            res.add(unknownName);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

What should the name of class UnknownName?

PS: I simplified the code for better redability, but I use a generic enrich() function that I call for all the find methods, so I don't have to dupe the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I adopted the suffix `Aggregator`, following the [Domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks) wording.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `SupplierDto` or `SupplierLegalOfficeDto`. DTO stands for Data Transfer Objects and it's commonly used for enriched models ([more here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171457/what-is-the-point-of-using-dto-data-transfer-objects)).

Also you shouldn't check `suppliers` for null as repository always returns a non-null list.

Comment: Mh, I dont' know. DTO is for data transfer, and I'm not transferring data, I'm creating a composer. I did some research and I found this article: https://www.programering.com/a/MDM2kjNwATc.html Now I'm undecided between BO and VO.

Comment: `BO: The full name is
Business object: service object
The main role is to encapsulate business logic as an object. The object may include one or more other objects.
For example, a resume, education experience, work experience, social relations and so on.
We can put the education has a corresponding PO, experience a corresponding PO, social relations corresponding to a PO.
BO object processing resumes to establish a corresponding resume, each BO contains the PO.
Such processing business logic, we can according to the BO to handle. `

Comment: `VO :
The ViewObject presentation layer object
The data object corresponding interface display. For a WEB page, an interface or SWT, SWING, with a VO object corresponding to the interface value. `

Comment: I read https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28301770/BO-business-object-classes-vs-VO-value-object-classes-in-java.html and now I think the correct term is `VO`.

Comment: Ok, it seems that `VO` it's a term used also for simple value objects. I think I'll adopt the term [Aggregate of DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks)